# Iso-F1 curve for Precision-Recall Curve

Tags: scikit-learn, precision-recall

I'm reading through Sklearn's tutorial on computing precision/recall! I came across this curve called "Iso-F1" curve they are plotting: [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-precision-recall-py).

I tried to read their code for generating it, but I can't seem to understand -- the idea seems to be fixing F1 score, generating x points, and then generate y based on the f-score?

```
for f_score in f_scores:
    x = np.linspace(0.01, 1)
    y = f_score * x / (2 * x - f_score)
    l, = plt.plot(x[y >= 0], y[y >= 0], color='gray', alpha=0.2)
    plt.annotate('f1={0:0.1f}'.format(f_score), xy=(0.9, y[45] + 0.02))
```

I can't find a lot of information about this curve online, and the only one that seems to be discussing about creating this curve:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8313

Another question I have is:

For precision-recall curve, if the curve is concave like below, does it mean I have a very good classifier?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By definition, an iso-F<sub>1</sub> curve contains all points in the precision/recall space whose F<sub>1</sub> scores are the same.

We can present as many iso-F<sub>1</sub> curves in the plot of a precision-recall curve as we'd like. E.g., one would contain all points for which F<sub>1</sub> equals 0.2, the second one all points for which F<sub>1</sub> equals 0.4, and so on. In the code snippet, each iteration of the loop plots a single iso-F<sub>1</sub> curve, and in each iteration variable `f_score` stores the value of F<sub>1</sub> corresponding to the current curve.

A point in the plot has coordinates $x$ and $y$ corresponding to a pair of recall and precision values. In the snippet, the $x$ (recall) coordinates of a curve are stored in `x` and are calculated with `np.linspace(0.01, 1)`, which gives 50 evenly spaced numbers over the interval $[0.01, 1]$.

For calculating the $y$ (precision) coordinate of a point for given values of recall and  F<sub>1</sub>, we have to turn to the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) of F<sub>1</sub> score:

$$
\mathrm{F}_{1} = 2 \cdot \frac{\mathrm{precision} \cdot \mathrm{recall}}{\mathrm{precision} + \mathrm{recall}}
$$

We can express $\mathrm{precision}$ as:

$$
\mathrm{precision} = \frac{\mathrm{F}_{1} \cdot \mathrm{recall}}{2 \cdot \mathrm{recall} - \mathrm{F}_{1}}
$$

`y = f_score * x / (2 * x - f_score)` corresponds to the equation above. With this we obtain the $y$ coordinates of the points of the iso-F<sub>1</sub> curve. The curve now can be plotted.

---

As for the second question: precision-recall curves are usually concave like yours. Your curve seems OK, but one needs to know about the specific task (domain, use-case, baseline solutions etc.) to tell if it's a very good classifier.